# Solaris 11 x 64 Cannot Enable SMB/CIFS > Missing Protocol?

Tags: solaris

I am configuring Solaris 11 on x64 as a test bench for a home storage system.

I cannot enable smb/cifs share> zfs set sharesmb=on
It says "protocol not installed" Where do I find this missing component and how do I install it?
Thanks a lot, Dan

Answer (score 4):

I don't know why, but the new solaris 11 does not include smb protocols by default. You must find smb packages from one of the repositories and install them yourself. So, to get your smb protocol up and running:

1. Install service/file-system/smb, system/file-system/smb via pkg command or the package manager interface.
2. Update /etc/pam.conf to include the line "other password required pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn".
3. Reset your smb user's password (to the same one if needed) by using "passwd your-user-name-goes-here".
4. Enable service using the command "svcadm enable -r smb/server".

Make sure to include the -r option. Without it, the dependencies do not start with the smb service.

Comment: Just a a clarification on what's installed and what isn't. Both `service/file-system/smb` (server) and `system/file-system/smb` (client) are part of a default Solaris install. Take a look in your global zone. However the `service/file-system/smb` pkg is not part of the *local zone* manifest and therefore by default doesn't exist for a plain vanilla zone install. You'll have to install it explicitly if you need it inside a local zone. I suspect this was true even in 2012 when this answer was written.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Dae, They've updated the instructions a bit for Solaris 11 UI, the line in `/etc/pam.conf` is now:

```
password required       pam_smb_passwd.so.1 nowarn
```

And you also have to call:

```
sudo smbadm enable-user [username]
```

[Source](https://blogs.oracle.com/paulie/entry/cifs_sharing_on_solaris_11)